# Android HTTPS Request with Volley

Tags: java, android, https, android-volley, ca

i'm trying to do https request using volley 
but i get this error response

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: >java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification >path not found.

what does this message means ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message appears because you need to add a certificate to your volley https request.

To do this add `HurlStack` to your request in volley.

```
    HurlStack hurlStack = new HurlStack() {
        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(java.net.URL url)
                throws IOException {
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) super
                    .createConnection(url);
            try {
                httpsURLConnection
                        .setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory(context));
                // httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return httpsURLConnection;
        }
    };
```

For the `getSSLSocketFactory` use this function.

```
 private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory(Context context)
            throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

// the certificate file will be stored in \app\src\main\res\raw folder path
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.YourCertificate);

        Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        caInput.close();

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf
                .getTrustManagers());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
```

For the `TrustManager` use this method:

```
private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers) {
        final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        return new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
                try {
                    if (certs != null && certs.length > 0) {
                        certs[0].checkValidity();
                    } else {
                        originalTrustManager
                                .checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                    }
                } catch (CertificateException e) {
                    Log.w("checkClientTrusted", e.toString());
                }
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
                try {
                    if (certs != null && certs.length > 0) {
                        certs[0].checkValidity();
                    } else {
                        originalTrustManager
                                .checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                    }
                } catch (CertificateException e) {
                    Log.w("checkServerTrusted", e.toString());
                }
            }
        } };
    }
```

Finally in the `RequestQueue` call the hurlstack:

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, hurlStack);
    requestQueue.add(Your Request);
```